# Ensuring an HTML form is filled out in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that performs calculations live as the user enters data.  However, some of the calculations require that certain fields are filled out first.

For instance, if I have 4 fields, and field 4 is a percentage of field 1, I have to make sure that the user has a value for field 1 before they can enter data into field 4.

One thought I have is to give each field a data-step attribute with a sequential number. When the form first comes up, all the fields are disabled except the first field. When valid data is entered into the first field, the fields for the next step are enabled.  This also assumes that if the user then blanks out field 1 that the rest of the fields are then blanked out and disabled again.

I'm pretty certain this solution would work, but would require a decent amount of JS code (jQuery) to ensure it works properly, as well as server-side validations. But one "gotcha" that I'm slightly puzzled on is if you do a submit and server-side validation fails and you render the form again, how to maintain the disabled/enabled state of the form fields? But I guess I'll deal with that problem after the current one.

So the question is, is this a decent solution to the problem of forms that must be filled out sequentially? Has anyone else found a better solution or a more elegant method than what I'm planning on implementing? I'm fine with generic concepts or ideas; I can pretty much code anything I need, I'm just not sure of best practice to this particular problem.

Comment: Why not just use default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't need to check an order but rather need to rule out the cases of form filled wrong (e.g. field 4 is filled, and field 1 is not).

I suggest you to allow user to enter anything they want, but to highlight the required fields as long as they're empty and to prevent form submittal until everything is correct.

Comment: The order has to be verified as well, as the calculations require data from previous fields. So field 1 must have a value when you enter in a percentage into field 4, because field 4's value is a percentage of field 1's value. So if I just let the user enter whatever, it would cause lots of problems. You are correct that I need to rule out invalid data, but the order is just as critical for my particular situation.

Comment: Let's imagine user enters 200 into the first field, then enters 25% into the fourth field, and then changes their mind and replaces the first field content with 300... are you trying to say that this user behavior should be prohibited?

Comment: No, that's something the user needs to be able to do.  The user is entering in data to perform a calculation and this calculation is running live as they type. So when they enter in 200 into field 1, there is a container somewhere that now says 200.  When they enter 25% into another field, the container is now updated with something like 250 (200 + .25(200)).  If the user changes field 1 to 100, the container should now display 125 (100 + .25(100)).  However, if the user removes the number in field 1, the percent field should also be blanked out so it's not running a calculation on nothing.

Comment: And what if the user uses the keyboard in such a way, that to replace 200 with 250, they first press `Del` three times and then enter 250? Whoops, you erased the fourth field content, and user has to enter 25% again. Don't ever erase the data user entered (unless you need to do so by the security reasons). You can just add a check into your calculation method so that it will erase the container when one of these two fields is not filled.

Comment: Hmm...you do make an excellent point. The more I think it through, the less I'm convinced I really need to force a fill-out order on the user. I think I may be able to get away with just letting them fill out the form in whatever order they want, and if all fields are not filled in for the calculation, just leave that calculation blank until all fields are filled in. Then when they submit the form, I can verify on both client and server sides that required fields are entered, so the final calculation should be determinable from the entered fields.

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is a good way of doing this. The JS code will not be that huge. You can use class names on the fields to determine which is the active one. You can always pass back some JS variables or a hidden field to tell the page which is active after server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not validate values in client-side? Process just like you've thought. Set `onchange` event handler to your inputs, and in handler validate the value. If correct, enable the next input, if incorrect, present disablings stay. Only few lines of script is required.

Comment: I will be validating client-side as well as server-side.

Answer (score -3):

```
      if(option1 == "" && option2 != "")
      {
           alert("Please fill options in a Sequence");
      }
      else if(option2 == "" && option3 != "")
      {
           alert("Please fill options in a Sequence");
      }
      else if(option3 == "" && option4 != "")
      {
           alert("Please fill options in a Sequence");
      }
      else if(option4 == "" && option5 != "")
      {
           alert("Please fill options in a Sequence");
      }
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don’t just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers